# Error log and display settings without ini_set()?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get error logging working so that errors don't show on my live website to people other than me (identified by my IP address), but it's not working because apparently `ini_set()` is disabled for my server due to "security reasons." Here's the code I was trying to use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', '/path/to/php-error.log');
```

I don't want to hard code the option to disable showing errors, because I do a check in my PHP pages to see if it's my IP address visiting the website and if so still show the errors.

Is there any way to log errors, dynamically changing whether they are displayed on the page or not, without using `ini_set()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at PHP's in-built custom error handling functions, which you could build your verification into. This replaces PHP's error handler with a custom function.

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if ( $ip != '127.0.0.1' ) return true; // Leave if not your IP

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

More info from the manual at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: nice copy paste - almost exact 1:1 copy of http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php -> Example #1 Error handling with set_error_handler() and trigger_error(). A link could have done it :)

Comment: Yes, this code is not my own. It is from the manual. No sense reinventing the wheel. A link by itself does not suffice because I want to show the OP where and how to compare IPs within the error handler function.

Comment: It is OK @set sail media :)

Comment: Thank you for the full example (copied or not :P), much appreciated.